# Can not connect to the Oracle Service

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I would like to connect to the running "orcl" Oracle database.

I don't have much experience on the Oracle administrator. I installed Oracle 12c in a Windows Server, as I see the "Oracle", "OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener" and "OracleServiceORCL" services are started in the machine.

I added the following to the "tnsnames.ora" file:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1539))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

I get "Ok" result from executing the "tnsping orcl" command.

I can login with "sqlplus / as sysdba" and when I query with "select name from v$database" command, I see "orcl" database is active.

But when I try to connect to the "orcl" database using Sqldeveloper, or when I execute

```
"sqlplus -L "system/password@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1539))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))"
```

I hit the issue below:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Aug 1 10:53:28 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

When executing the "lsnrctl status" command:

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 01-AUG-2019 12:16
:04

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1539)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                01-AUG-2019 09:38:59
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 37 min. 5 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Administrator\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\n
etwork\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\Administrator\virtual\diag\tnslsnr\WIN-91FKK175
962\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=WIN-91FKK175962)(PORT=1539)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521_1ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

How can I connect to the orcl database? What I am missing in configuration or anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried `sqlplus system/password@orcl`?

Comment: Yes I have tried and get the same "ORA-12514" error.

Comment: Remove the space characters from database connection string, i.e. `system/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1539))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))` Perhaps enclose it by double-quotes.

Comment: Removing spaces did not help. The same result. :(

Comment: Has the `orcl` database been started? See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e10845/admin.htm#NTQRF214

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is just

```
sqlplus [user]/[Password]@[connect identifier]
```

eg. your user is `system`, Password is `pswd` and connect identifier in your example is 'ORCL'

so your sqlplus command would be:

```
sqlplus system/pswd@orcl
```

if you DB is installed on your local machine that it should be also be possible just to conect to localhost instead of  service

```
sqlplus system/pswd@localhost
```

Comment: Yes I have tried and get the same "ORA-12514" error. Looks like something wrong with the "orcl" even it is active database. I checked both querying from v$database and v$thread system tables. Do you have another recommendation?

Comment: try to connect to localhost

Comment: When I try localhost, I hit this: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: check the listener Status and add result in your question: `lsnrctl status`

Comment: Added the "lsnrctl status" result to the question.

Comment: @Softengilker I suppose the listener listens to the wrong server name: `WIN-91FKK175962`. I think it should be localhost. look in the listener file did you enter the name during installation? Looks like your pc name

Comment: Thank you @hotfix. I also realized it. But in none of the .ora files, server name is written. I also added the following line to the "hosts" file in the Windows: 127.0.0.1 WIN-91FKK175962  localhost

Comment: @Softengilker do you able to connect now?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not :( I am in the same position.